# Can a wizard use the spell Levitate on a target and shoot him with attacking spells that don't require concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, wizard

Can a wizard use the spell Levitate on a target and shoot it with attacking spells that don't require concentration or can somebody else shoot the target?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Both the wizard and other people can attack the target

[*Levitate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/levitate) has no special ending conditions for the target being attacked (the text description of levitate would have to say so). Further, a wizard can keep concentrating on a spell and cast other spells that don't require concentration (see [this exact question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79407/can-i-cast-a-no-concentration-spell-while-concentrating-on-another)). This means that casting levitate on a target and then having people ranged attack the target is a perfectly valid strategy.

This is actually a common strategy to employ against enemies that have no ranged attack options (do note that unwilling targets get a single Constitution saving throw to avoid the effect when the spell is cast). Barring some outside help the target is usually doomed.

Comment: This is why all of my melee-types are heavier than 500 lbs. No wizard is going to beat me with this technique